# How Angular packages are build

Tags: angular, webpack

What are the different files generated by the Angular build? I notice there are 6 of them:

- `main.js`
- `polyfill.js`
- `runtime.js`
- `scripts.js`
- `vendor.js`
- `styles.js`

I suppose Angular uses `webpack` to make builds. But I am not able to find any resource which could explain what these files contain. For eg. does `main.js` contain my application code? If I am using 3rd party `npm` packages, do they go in `scripts.js` or `vendor.js`? Why there is a `.js` file for `styles`? (I thought `styles` were a `.css` thing).

Comment: Which version of angular? angular cli?

Comment: Angular 6, cli 6.2.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the last versions there is a [differential loading](https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27) implemented so it genererates two of each of this files one in ES5 and second in ES2015

Between the filename and the extension there is also a hash. In case of differential loading there is also a js version behind the file separated with `-` so file name looks like this `name-jsversion.hash.js`

**runtime.js** - in the link it's called `inline` it was renamed in Angular 6.0 to `runtime`

> This is a webpack loader. A tiny file with Webpack utilities that are
> needed to load the other files.

**vendor.js**

> This file contains any libraries imported into your app (app.module), including the Angular libraries. Third party libraries imported into your app also get compiled into this file (e.g. lodash, moment etc).
>
> *Warning* this file is HUGE after a dev compile (ng build) because it contains everything required to compile Angular in the browser. Always
> run a prod build (ng build –prod) before releasing your app to
> production. A prod build runs the Ahead of Time (AoT) compilation and
> performs tree-shaking.

**main.js**

> This is where the action happens. This file contains all your code.

**polyfills.js**

> This one should be self explanatory. It contains all the polyfills you declare in your polyfills.ts file.

**scripts.js**

> This one should also be self explanatory. It contains the scripts you declare in the scripts section of your `angular.json` file.

**1.js** or **2.js** or ... - the number is incrementing. If there are no lazy loaded modules this file isn't generated.

> This is a file that contains a lazy loaded module, as many lazy loaded modules you have that many files will generate.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I don't have `1.js` generated. Also, what is the difference/use of `scripts.js`. Isn't it duplicate of `vendor.js`?

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to resolve this issue which I suppose is linked to incorrect use/call of scripts. Would you be able to look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177855/theme-and-mode-path-infer-issue-with-ace-js-and-angular

Comment: You don't have to have `1.js` It's generated only when you have some module lazy loaded.

Comment: got it. If you get a chance, please look at the other problem as well I am facing

Comment: got it. If you get a chance, please look at the other problem as well I am facing

Comment: what about styles.js ?

Comment: The first link is gambling spam.

Comment: @Alex Oh thanks for notice, it's removed now.