# Large Angular 12 application - how can I manage js files

Tags: angular

My angular 12 application is large and takes time to load the first time for any user. No api is triggered until all js files are loaded. If I see in Dev Tools (js enabled), You see the below screen shot. Is there anyway I can lazy load these files? [image]

Comment: Why do you have so many js files? The default config there are about 6 js files, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/60177478/1260204. These do have cash busting hashes in the names but still only 6. How is your application structured or what are you loading that you have this many js files and also without prefixes in the name.

Comment: To manage JS files in a large Angular 12 application: use lazy loading, split code into smaller modules, use tree shaking, optimize code, use third-party libraries carefully, and consider using code splitting tools.

Comment: These are built minified js files

Comment: It is hard to say because we have no access to your structure or your code. If you want more help you need to provide an [mcve] that illustrates the problem configured in the same manner your application is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [lazyloading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) your routes in the app.routing.ts should look like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foobar',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./foobar.module').then(m => m.FoobarModule),
  }];
```

The module will be loaded only when the user navigates to the route.

Comment: I already have that implemented

Comment: My question is that after all those js files I get my apis for the home page running. Why does all js files get loaded at once? I do have loadChildren implemented

Comment: Could you show your routing module? And do you have circular dependencies ?

Comment: Thanks @heaxyh for the heads up. I had a configuration called PreloadAllModules in my routes. By removing that lazy loading works correctly